# CSS Centering menu

Tags: css, positioning

I'm using a jquery pluging to create a drop down menu   - http://dev7studios.com/dropit/#

The HTML and CSS can be seen below.

The problem is that I cannot center the menu (and dropdown items) within the wrapper div

```
   <ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Some Action 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Action 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Action 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul
```

---

```
.menu {
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;   // THIS DOES NOT WORK 
    width: 99px;

}

.dropit {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.dropit .dropit-trigger { position: relative; }
.dropit .dropit-submenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0; /* dropdown left or right */
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    min-width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.dropit .dropit-open .dropit-submenu { display: block; }
```

Can anyone help?

Pete

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.dropit-submenu{ left: -33%; }` to your css.

**Note:** The exact value of 'left' may need to be adjusted dynamically depending on the width of the element - **It'll be 1/3rd of your element's width**

Comment: You're welcome :). Please close the question as 'answered' (click the tick)